# Mysql forum - get number of replies

Tags: mysql

I'm making a very simple forum with one table called forum_posts. I store both the replies and the posts in that same table because I've found that works pretty well for comments system I made before.

If the post is a reply, it has a reply_id that is the post_id of the post it is replying to. If it is a 'root post' so to speak, it has a 0 for the reply_id.

I already have the number of views. But I'd like to get the number of replies for each record in the results.

How would I do that?

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.store_name, p.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_text, p.views, p.creation_timestamp, p.update_timestamp
FROM forum_posts AS p
INNER JOIN accounts AS a
ON p.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE p.reply_id > 0
```

As you can probably guess, I'm making the forum listings where people choose a forum post to go and view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to join posts against itself and count it to get the number of replies. This isn't particularly efficient over millions of forum posts - most forums denormalize this and maintain a post count attribute separately.

However, in keeping with what you have, something like (untested)...

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.store_name, cp.* FROM
(
    SELECT p.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_text, p.views, p.creation_timestamp, 
        p.update_timestamp,  p.account_id, (COUNT(*) - 1) as replies
    FROM forum_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN forum_posts AS p1 ON p1.reply_id > 0 AND p1.reply_id = p.post_id
    GROUP BY p.post_id
)
AS cp
INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON cp.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE cp.replies > 0
```

The end `WHERE` is optional. I just copied it from your first query. It's also worth noting that this is MySQL specific as it uses the `GROUP BY` without a full list of non-aggregated columns (but you tagged your question as MySQL so no problem).

Comment: Ah yes, not so sure about subqueries. As you say not so efficient. Maybe I should reconsider my structure hmm.

Comment: It's not really a subquery in the traditional sense. It's just wrapping the result before you join it to `accounts` so that only needs to happen once. Think of it as a poor mans CTE. If you do it without, then the DB will need to join against every reply when you are not using that data.

Comment: I think I am going to just create a "replies" field that is incremented when a reply is made. When solutions get like this it's probably better to go with the less extravagant approach. I'll thumb you up when it lets me :)

Comment: Could you please explain why do you use `COUNT(*)-1`? Aren't you underestimating the number of replies by 1 everywhere, except in the case of unanswered posts?

Comment: @Strawberry Touché. I should probably qualify my generalisations. That said, many of the popular open source forums have denormalised replies in this way (PHPBB, PunBB, ModernBB, MyBB ... and so on). I can't actually find one that doesn't.

Comment: @striving_coder Good spot. I guess it should be changed to `COUNT(p1.reply_id)` to only count replies, and no subtraction. I've closed my fiddle for this question now to test.

Comment: @AndySavage: `COUNT(p1.reply_id)` is a nice solution - much better than my outer query approach!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT account_id, store_name, post_id, post_title, post_text, views, creation_timestamp, update_timestamp, IF(reply_id IS NOT NULL, replies, 0)
FROM (
    SELECT a.account_id, a.store_name, p.post_id, p.post_title, p.post_text, p.views, p.creation_timestamp, p.update_timestamp, r.reply_id, COUNT(*) as replies
    FROM forum_posts AS p
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a
    ON p.account_id = a.account_id
    LEFT JOIN forum_posts AS r
    ON p.post_id = r.reply_id
    WHERE p.reply_id = 0
    GROUP BY p.post_id
) AS sq
```

It also seems that you need `p.reply_id = 0` if you want to show only "root" posts (forum threads) rather than replies.

Outer query makes sure that the posts with no replies (which are still returned in the inner query) are printed with the number of replies 0 rather than 1 (which would be incorrect obviously).

Comment: Looks interesting but it doesn't seem to like the GROUP BY p.post_id on the first line. spits out an error.

Comment: @AmyNeville: Oops, sorry: `GROUP BY` should be on the very last line.

Comment: Your last join (on forum_posts again) should also be `LEFT` not `INNER`, else you will exclude posts with no replies.

Comment: @AndySavage: Yep, you're right, thanks! Also had to take care of the correct counting number of replies for these posts with no replies by placing original query into subquery. BTW, I think your answer might be the problem stemming from the same thing - see my comment.